# error when searching through 2d array ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following grids (connect four)

```
grid1 = [
  [nil, nil, nil],
  [1, nil, nil],
  [1, nil, nil],
  [1, nil, nil]
]
grid2 = [
  [nil, nil, nil],
  [nil, nil, 1],
  [nil, nil, 1],
  [nil, nil, 1]
]

grid3 = [
  [nil, nil, nil],
  [nil, nil, nil],
  [nil, nil, nil],
  [1, 1, 1]
]
```

and this is the method I created to find three 1's in a vertical row and return the next available slot above

```
def searchArray(array)
  array.each_with_index do |y, yi|
    y.each_with_index do |x, xi|
      if array[yi][xi] != nil && array[yi][xi] == array[yi+1][xi] && array[yi][xi] == array[yi+2][xi]
        return v = [yi-1, xi]
      end
    end
  end
end


searchArray(grid2)
```

When I call the method on grid1, and grid 2 it works great but when I call it on Grid 3 the grid where the 1's are placed on the bottom row I get this error

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
(repl):28:in `block (2 levels) in searchArray'
(repl):27:in `each'
(repl):27:in `each_with_index'
(repl):27:in `block in searchArray'
(repl):26:in `each'
(repl):26:in `each_with_index'
(repl):26:in `searchArray'
(repl):36:in `<main>'
```

Not sure what's going on
Thanks

Comment: Indentation, please. That code is slammed left and it's barely readable as-is.

Comment: I think you're walking off the end of the array here. You're testing `array[yi][xi]` and then go ahead and presume `array[yi+1]` exists, which it may not.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: To format code within a paragraph surround it with backticks (`\``). To format a block of code, indent 4 spaces or select all the code and click on the icon `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your code, simplified slightly<sup>1</sup>:

```
def search_array(array)
  array.each_with_index do |y, yi|
    y.each_with_index do |x, xi|
      return [yi-1, xi] if x != nil && x == array[yi+1][xi] && x == array[yi+2][xi]
    end
  end
end
```

You go one row at a time, then for each element in that row, check if that element is not `nil` and if so, determine whether the two elements below it have the same non-nil value. If you reach the penultimate (next-to-last) row, `yi = array.size - 2`, you will compare `x` with `array[yi+2][xi]`, which equals `array[array.size][xi]`, which in turn equals `nil[xi]`. However, `nil` has no method `[]` so an *undefined method* exception is raised. Pay close attention to those error messages; often, as here, they guide you to the error.

Another problem is that if you found `1`'s in the first three rows of a column `j` you would return the index `[-1, j]`, `-1` being `0-1`. You don't want that either.

I understand that you also wish to determine if dropping a coin in a column results in four-in-a-row horizontally. You could check both vertically and horizontally as follows.

```
def search_array(arr)
  arr.first.each_index do |j|
    r = arr.each_index.find { |i| arr[i][j] == 1 }
    next if r == 0
    r = r.nil? ? arr.size-1 : r-1
    return [r,j] if below?(arr,r,j) || left?(arr,r,j) || right?(arr,r,j)
  end
  nil
end

def below?(arr,r,j)
  r < arr.size-3 && (1..3).all? { |i| arr[r+i][j] == 1 }
end

def right?(arr,r,j)
  j < arr.first.size-3 && (1..3).all? { |i| arr[r][j+i] == 1 }
end

def left?(arr,r,j)
  j >= 3 && (1..3).all? { |i| arr[r][j-i] == 1 }
end
```

```
grid4 = [
  [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
  [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
  [nil, nil,   1, nil, nil],
  [nil, nil,   1,   1,   1],
  [  1,   1,   1, nil,   1]
]

grid5 = [
  [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
  [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
  [nil, nil,   1, nil, nil],
  [nil,   1,   1, nil, nil],
  [nil,   1,   1, nil,   1]
]
```

```
search_array grid1 #=> [0, 0] (vertical)
search_array grid2 #=> [0, 2] (vertical)
search_array grid3 #=> nil
search_array grid4 #=> [3, 1] (horizontal)
search_array grid5 #=> [1, 2] (vertical)
```

Note that if you wish to also check for four-in-a-row diagonnal you could change:

```
return [r,j] if below?(arr,r,j) || left?(arr,r,j) || right?(arr,r,j)
```

to

```
return [r,j] if below?(arr,r,j) || left?(arr,r,j) || right?(arr,r,j) ||
  top_left_to_bottom_right?(arr,r,j) || bottom_left_to_top_right?(arr,r,j)
```

and add the additional methods `top_left_to_bottom_right?` and `bottom_left_to_top_right?`.

<sup>1. I changed the name of your method to `search_array` because Ruby has a convention to use [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for the naming of variables and methods. You don't have to adopt that convention but 99%+ of Rubiests do.</sup>

Comment: Hi, great explanation. Really liking the first explanation. How would you make this work horizontally?(to get the next column that needs to be placed horizontally) I'm a beginner and this is helping me alot! thank you

Comment: return [i,j] if array[i][j].nil? && [1,2,3].all? { |k| array[i][j-k] == 1 } this is working for me

Comment: my problem is when using a bigger grid and checking 3 in a row horizontal to the right it works but when I wanna check them to the left its not working like so

Comment: `grid4 = [
  [nil,nil,nil,nil,1,1,1],
  [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
  [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
  [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
  [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
  [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil] ]`

Comment: in this case I would need to use return [i,j] if array[i][j].nil? && [1,2,3].all? { |k| array[i][j+k] == 1 } on the last line to catch this way how can i combine this with this return [i,j] if array[i][j].nil? && [1,2,3].all? { |k| array[i][j-k] == 1 } to check for both ways?

Comment: def search_array_horiz(array)
  (0..array.size-4).each do |i|
    (0..array.first.size-1).each do |j|
      if array[i][j].nil? && [1,2,3].all? { |k| array[i][j-k] == 1 }
      return [i,j]
      elsif array[i][j].nil? && [1,2,3].all? { |k| array[i][j+k] == 1 }
      return [i,j]
      end
    end
  end
  nil
end

Comment: wow that works the `search_array(array.transpose).reverse` not sure what transformation? also with this I get an undefined method reverse error when the grid is filled with only nils. thank you

Comment: `search_array(array.transpose.reverse)&.reverse` this seems to work

Comment: it's ok, still trying to work at it. Thank you so much

Comment: See my updated answer. I've deleted all my comments (and will delete this one after you've seen it) because they dealt with a flawed suggestion for checking values horizontally. You may want to the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve a lot of problems here by simplifying this code using [`dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-dig):

```
def search_array(array)
  array.each_with_index do |y, yi|
    y.each_with_index do |x, xi|
      stack = (0..2).map { |o| array.dig(yi + o, xi) }

      if (stack == [ 1, 1, 1 ])
        return [ yi - 1, xi ]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Where `dig` can poke around and not cause exceptions if it misses the end of the array. Here `map` is used to quickly pull out an *N* high stack. You can do `1..2` or `0..4` or whatever is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest a slight different approach, this is not a complete solution, just a start. It should also help to catch the four.

First map the not `nil` indexes of the grid, let's consider `grid3`:

```
mapping = grid3.flat_map.with_index{ |y, yi| y.map.with_index { |x, xi| [xi, yi] if x }.compact }
#=> [[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Then group by first and second element to get the columns and rows:

```
cols = mapping.group_by(&:first) #=> {0=>[[0, 3]], 1=>[[1, 3]], 2=>[[2, 3]]}
rows = mapping.group_by(&:last) #=> {3=>[[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3]]}
```

Now, if you want to look for three elements in a row or in a column:

```
cols.keep_if { |_,v| v.size == 3 } #=> {}
rows.keep_if { |_,v| v.size == 3 } #=> {3=>[[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3]]}
```

The first line says there are no columns with three element aligned.
The second line says that row with index 3 has three elements aligned and indexes are `[[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3]]`.

---

Next step it to check that there are no gaps amongst elements. For example in a 4x4 grid you could get also `[[0, 3], [1, 3], [3, 3]]` which are three elements, but there is a gap in `[2, 3]`,